# HC-05 Bluetooth module not recognized by mobile phone

Tags: serial, bluetooth

What is happening with the bluetooth module is a bit weird. It apparently works perfectly, it gets recognized by my desktop computer and my laptop, but never gets listed on my mobile phone.

I've configured it in many ways, and it's always the same: it gets listed everywhere, but not in the mobile phone.

I know for sure that the mobile phone works, because I can connect it with other computers, and other devices get listed there too.

My configuration steps are:

```
AT
AT+ORGL
AT+RESET
AT+NAME=TEST
AT+ROLE=0
AT+POLAR=1,0
AT+RESET
AT+INIT
AT+INQ
```

I set the original from fabric just in case, and reset the device. Then configure it to set the name, slave role, invert the status pin so it goes low when is paired, and reset again to start with the new config.

Then I init the module and start inquiring.

What could be happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which mobile phone do you have? I have gotten it to work on several Android based phones, but the iPhone do not see it.

Comment: @Suirnder Its a Android based phone. Android version 2.3.6.

Comment: Make sure you disconnect the AT-mode wire. Then it goes in to connection-mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found the problem.

The HC-05 modules (and probably the HC-06) comes with a Device Class 0 as default. Wich most of the lets say "secure devices" nowdays request the device class to enumerate it corectly.

I've setted the decive class to 00001 (this major class is designed for computers) and finally it was recognized by android without problem.

```
AT+CLASS=1
```

It was tested with BlueTerm for Android from Google Play and with the default search for bluethoot devices from comfiguration.

Info can be found:

- [Here](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/F3O/K70G/H1LWQ0PO/F3OK70GH1LWQ0PO.pdf)
- [Here (Mirror)](http://www.seinoxygen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/HC-05.pdf)